# Possible to turn the Alert to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, alert

i was wondering if it is possible to turn the alert window into an HTML page that i have created. So when the if statement is true then an HTML page opens instead of a Java Alert prompt

```
if (userName == dataArray[i].substring(0,dataArray[i].indexOf("="))) {
                                alert("You have already contacted us.");    
                                nameFound = true;
                                break;
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Java is *not* JavaScript. The naming is confusing, but the two are not related.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a popup window:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/');
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

Comment: I guess using Google in examples is not uncommon. :-P

Comment: Lol! I'll change it to the normal test website. Google.com is just so automatic for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
if(condition){
    window.location = "http://www.example.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the purpose of this new window, if you want to display a new page is the following way:

```
 if (yourCondition) {
                            window.open(url,name,param1,paran2); 
                            nameFound = true;
                            break;
                }
    }
```

If you want to display a message, I recommend you to use the jquery plugin, call jquery ui, in the following link , http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/, you have a demo and the source code, is really cool.

see you!!